# How can I add modding system in my client-server multiplayer game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a client-server multiplayer game in unity. I successfully added all the basic stuff. Now, on the server side, I added a basic mod system (like spigot/bukkit in Minecraft). I thought the server sided base code should be closed, create a api for that modding system. How Could I achieve it without opening the base code of the server.

Note: My modding system should have Event Listeners and Main class handler like Spigot/bukkit (on the server side), also please tell me how to create c# DLL for that mod and how to call the start class on runtime.

Edit: I asked the question on my phone, so for any spelling mistakes , I am sorry.

Code Example:
Client sends a player movement packet, the server will handle the packet,
and send the respective position of the player to himself and all other
players. Now I want to tell the plugin/mod that a player is moving and the
plugin/mod will execute their code.

Comment: For event handler i have an example like PlayerMoveEvent with getPlayer() and getLocation() methods. I know how to implement these but how to invoke lots of method which takes this PlayerMoveEvent class a paramter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a UnityGame, you should look at [Harmony 2](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony).
Harmony has a big flexibility and enable users to make C# lib mods on mostly everything in your game.

To create c# DLL as a mod. You must create a new Visual Studio project on the same .NET version of your game. And references all dll in the /Managed folder of your compiled game.